# Returning a list of objects

Tags: java, design-patterns

Please review the following code. Methods `getFirsts` and `getSeconds`, both of which are `private`, return a list of objects which implement `CommonInterface`. Is this a good or bad design?

```
@Override
public final List<? extends CommonInterface> getObjects(final CommonEnum type) {
    if (type == null) {
        return new ArrayList<CommonInterface>();
    }
    switch (type) {
        case FIRST:
            return getFirsts();
        case SECOND:
            return getSeconds();
        default:
            return null;
    }
}
```

Comment: If this list returned through getFirsts or getSeconds are mutable, you have to realize that you are exposing the lists to mutation to any caller of "getObjects" (which is public).

Comment: my idea was to expose only one method in the interface and hide the if else/ switch logic in one method, to prevent such statements in other places in the code and to get by the caller the list of appropriate objects only by CommonEnum value. I am asking because I often using such structures so I'm curious the opinions.

Comment: Cory's point is that by returning the actual private list you are allowing callers to modify it directly. If this is what you want, perhaps you might want to rethink that part of your design. Also, why is `null` an acceptable value for `type`? It would help to have a concrete example with how you use this idiom.

Comment: @corykendall: I think your comment would be worth an answer.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's hard to say anything since it seems rather a pseudo-code. Anyway, two notes which you might find useful:

1. I guess you could replace the switch-case structure with polymorphism. Two useful reading:

   - *Refactoring: Improving the Design of Existing Code* by *Martin Fowler*: *Replacing the Conditional Logic on Price Code with Polymorphism*
   - [Replace Conditional with Polymorphism](http://sourcemaking.com/refactoring/replace-conditional-with-polymorphism)
2. Are you sure that returning `null` in the `default` is fine? I'd consider returning an empty list (as it returns when `type == null`) or throwing an exception (`IllegalStateException`, for example) if it's a programming error. (See: *The Pragmatic Programmer: From Journeyman to Master* by *Andrew Hunt* and *David Thomas*: *Dead Programs Tell No Lies*)